# Making simple loop in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

In the PostGIS SQL Editor, I just want to make a loop to make this function work

This query is to give the UTM Zone number to one column of Global DTM raster table

```
For Loopid = 0 to 1000, then execute the following statments:

UPDATE public.globaldtm 
SET "UTM" = loopid 
WHERE rid IN (SELECT rid FROM globaldtm WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,(select geom from utm where gid =loopid)));
```

[image]

How do I write a simple code inside this SQL editor to make the loop work?

Comment: please describe what the query does verbally

Comment: Why are you looping.  That is normally not what you want to do.

Comment: Because I have to do it 1000 times, you see the Loopid is changing from 1 to 1000.

Comment: You don't need that loop. `TOP 1000` would work the same

Answer (score 7):

This is doing the same thing without the loop:

```
UPDATE public.globaldtm 
SET "UTM" = sub.gid 
FROM (
    SELECT rid, sub.gid
    FROM globaldtm 
    JOIN utm ON ST_Intersects(rast, utm.geom) = 1
    ORDER BY utm.gid, rid
    LIMIT 1000) as sub
WHERE rid = sub.rid
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't postgresql has `limit` instead of `top n`?

Comment: oppps :) My mistake

Comment: Weird phrasing; `LIMIT` typically appears after `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Updated the code. Been doing to much TSQL.

Answer (score 3):

There are two more answers which is more suitable to my question. I got it from Stack Overflow.

1st :

```
UPDATE public.globaldtm 
SET UTM = loopid
FROM generate_series(0, 1000) as x(loopid) -- Added this line
WHERE rid IN (SELECT rid FROM globaldtm WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,(select geom from utm where gid =loopid)));
```

2nd :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateValuesWithLoop()
RETURNS void
AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR Loopid  IN 0..1000 LOOP
     UPDATE public.globaldtm 
     SET "UTM" = loopid 
     WHERE rid IN (SELECT rid FROM globaldtm WHERE ST_Intersects(rast,(select geom from utm where gid =loopid)));
  END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Execute the function:

```
select updateValuesWithLoop()
```